# How to find subtimespan in a timespan like a string in python

Tags: python, timespan

I have a string of a timespan like this:

```
timespan = '08.00-14:00'
```

I want to know if this timespan is at least n hours, for example 2 hours:

```
if timespan >= 2:
    do something
```

Comment: What about `"23:00-01:00"`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Good catch - I deleted my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: You can try something like

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

timespan = '23.00-01:00'

start_time, end_time = timespan.split('-')
start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H.%M')
end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, '%H:%M')

if end_time <= start_time:
    # end_time is on the next day, add 1 day to end_time
    end_time += timedelta(days=1)

duration = end_time - start_time

if duration >= timedelta(hours=2):
    print("The duration is at least 2 hours.")
else:
    print("The duration is less than 2 hours.")
```

Comment: What about `"23:00-01:00"`?